# Stripe API "save my info" prevent default check

Tags: stripe-payments, default-value, user-experience

I create a checkout session using the Stripe API, and then redirect to `checkout.stripe.com` with it.

Everything works fine, except "Have my info for 1-ckick checkout with Link" is checked by default, and I'd like to make it unchecked by default. I think this may have been a recent change with Stripe's interface, as I don't remember it being enabled by default before.

Is there a way to change this, or is this a fixed aspect of their UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe added an option in your Dashboard settings where you can control whether you want this behaviour on or off by default. You can find the option [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/link#features).